# Constructor error when adding image slider

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to add a image slider to my app but i'm stuck at error "Cannot resolve"SlideMode(int)". I have no idea how to fix this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    ImageSlider imageSlider = findViewById(R.id.slider);

    List<SlideModel> slideModels = new ArrayList<>();


    slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.devonhouse));

    imageSlider.setImageList(slideModels,ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP);


}
```

}

Comment: What is SlideModel? Can you show its constructors?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the line

```
imageSlider.setImageList(slideModels,ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP);
```

The scaling(CENTER_CROP) of the images that you have done in the above line **shouldn't be done there**.

The scaling should be done while adding the images in the ArrayList "slideModels".

```
slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.devonhouse, "",ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP ));
```

Now the final code will look something like: -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

ImageSlider imageSlider = findViewById(R.id.slider);

List<SlideModel> slideModels = new ArrayList<>();

slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.devonhouse, "",ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP ));

imageSlider.setImageList(slideModels);

}
```

Please let me know if it works.